# Using sr036 only for the regulated output

Tags: power-supply

I'll start by admitting I am a newbie to electronics. I would like to use the [sr036 IC](http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/sr03.pdf) for only the regulated output. So I left out the GN2470 transistor out of the circuit I've built. The problem is that there is no output now on the regulated output pin. Is the bipolar transistor mandatory also for the regulated output? Or could I use something else than a GN2470 / MOSFET transistor in order to have the regulated output as described in the datasheet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have never used this device, but most likely, the 18V unregulated output is the sole input for the regulated supply, and not the high voltage input. This looks like an essentially linear device, and it is not practical to regulate what could be 300V (pk.) down to 3.3 or 5V using just a linear regulator.

This can be seen in the diagram at the top right of page 4:

[image: functional block diagram of SR036 from page 4 of datasheet]

So, yes, you do need the switching transistor, otherwise there will be no unregulated output, and hence no regulated output either.

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question. Apparently I cannot upvote and accept your answer do to lack of reputation points.

Comment: @Copiltembel it doesn't matter. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making this an answer rather than a comment mainly so I can put this essential message in large letters.

#### ALL parts of this supply MUST be regarded as being at **FULL** AC mains voltage at all times. They really MAY be.

This type of IC and power supply have their place BUT are lethally dangerous and best not used except by experts who understand the shortcomings and dangers and can and will allow for them.

The data sheet puts it more subtly and their warning may be missed. They say:

- **WARNING!!! Galvanic isolation is not provided. Dangerous
  voltages are present when connected to the AC line. It is
  the responsibility of the designer to assure adequate
  safeguards are in place to protect the end user from
  electrical shock.**

Essentially, all users need to know that "THIS MACHINE KILLS".

[image]

So,  to the actual answer:

Attempting to use the IC without the pass transistor is somewhat like attempting to run a Marathon but only wanting to use one's head, discarding the body and legs. ie it not be done without destroying the basic system AND it doesn't work.

As Oleksandr says, the external device is essential. The system works by turning on the pass transistor when the mains input voltage is low enough to be 'safe and useful', for some values of safe. The IC is the brain. The transistor 'does the work'. To run this marathon you must have both.